# How to pass argument to Powershell from PERL and retain the output?

Tags: perl, powershell

I'm trying to pass an argument to a Powershell script via PERL and then retain the output for use later in the script. I cannot seem to get it to work.

**PERL**

```
$var= 1000;

my @output = `powershell.exe C:\\Workspace\\Utilities\\pathtoscript.ps1`.` $var`;
foreach (@output)
{
   print $_;
}
```

The powershell script appears to fail as if it's not receiving the argument. The powershell script is supposed to use that value and determine a new value based on the original value and pass it back to PERL to be used later in the PERL script.

I have attached another example of what i tried, which also fails in the same

**Alternate Script**

```
$center = 1000;
print "Getting business unit...\n";
my $renamecmd = 'Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File C:\Workspace\Utilities\get_business_unit.ps1'." $center";
my @output = `$renamecmd`;
foreach (@output)
{
   print $_;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't Perl, but assuming the backticks are invoking a command like in Bash, you're invoking one command with no parameter, and trying to run the variable as if it was another command. Then concatenate the results together. That doesn't look like it would work at all. Still, explain what *you* mean by "not correctly", what should happen and what actually happens. Nobody can guess what's going wrong.

Comment: Updated thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... 
I also wrapped it in a fuction

```
sub getvalue{
print "Getting value...\n";
my $renamecmd = 'Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File C:\Workspace\Utilities\pathtofile.ps1'." $val";
my @output = `$renamecmd`;
foreach (@output) {
   print $_;
}
}
```